# ¿Cómo ejecutar código de PostgreSQL desde Visual Studio Code?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plugin, heroku, vscode

Intento utilizar un plugin de VS Code (pgsql v0.0.8) para que el editor sirva como cliente para PostgreSQL, debido a que necesito uno para conectarme a una base de datos que me provee el cloud Heroku (Heroku Postgres).

Para utilizar este plugin debía configurar en el espacio de trabajo la URI de conexión a la base de datos, lo cual si hice. También reinicié la aplicación por si las dudas. Pero, al momento de ejecutar las consultas, en la terminal de salida de VS Code me devolvía un mensaje del plugin informando: "pgsql: can't spawn child proceess".

También en la información del plugin decía que debía asegurarme de que la configuración "psql" estuviera en la ruta ejecutable del sistema operativo. Pero, en caso de que no, ¿cómo debo configurar eso?

- No estoy utilizando pgAdmin porque no me funciona correctamente.
- Estoy en Windows 7.
- Plugin de VS Code: pgsql v0.0.8.
- No tengo instalado el servidor de PostgreSQL de manera local.

Comment: no se cual de las extensiones de PostgreSQL para VS Code esté usando , pero en tu PATH debes declarar dónde está la ruta del psql, para poder ejecutar. Ese deberia estar donde tienes instalado de manera local tu instalacion de Postgre. Podrias intentar con docker y un container que tenga posgre y desde ahi probar esa seria una opcion o con vangrant y solo compartir el archivo sql que contiene psql.

Comment: ¿Necesito tener instalado el servidor de Postgre de manera local para poder conectarme a un servidor remoto? Eso fue lo que entendí.

Comment: asi es debes de tener instalado Postgres de manera local

Comment: Revisar este link de esta web: https://data-nerd.blog/2020/02/06/postgresql-extension-for-vscode/